# accessing ListViewItem.Bounds or ListViewItem.GetBounds(..) throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net, listviewitem

I get an Exception at lvi.Bounds
But I don't know what i can check to stop it.
It seems to only happen when I am displaying the control and call this method on my Resize event, or sizeChanged, or after I have created everything, but before my code returns to Windows.

```
private List<uint> GetIndexes(ListView vv)
    {
        List<uint> ret = new List<uint>();
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in vv.Items)
        {
            uint uiKey = ((uint)lvi.Tag);
            if (!requestedImgs.Contains(uiKey) && lvi.Bounds.IntersectsWith(vv.ClientRectangle) && DctImages.Contains(uiKey))
            {
                ret.Add(uiKey);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason i have found for this is that I was calling

```
itemPanel1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
itemPanel1.Sort();
```

after I had added the items, and calling

```
itemPanel1.Select();
```

before I then went through all my items and checked the bounds, which caused the exception above.

So i don't understand it, but have found a fix.